# My new definition of the footer is not used in the table of contents: why?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

With this MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[OLF]{{\footnotesize \textForFooter}}
\fancyhf[ORF]{{\footnotesize \thepage}}
\fancyhf[ERF]{{\footnotesize \textForFooter}}
\fancyhf[ELF]{{\footnotesize \thepage}}

\def\textForFooter{test}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{One}
\section{Two}

\end{document}
```

the footer of the table of contents is

[image]

whereas the footer of the next page is

[image]

Why so?

Comment: Have you tried `\thispagestyle{fancy}` immediately after `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: It works. Do you understand why? Can you write an answer?

Comment: Please see the answer I posted a little while ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the `book` document class uses the `plain` page style for the *first* pages of chapter-like document units and the `headings` page style for all other pages. (Aside: The LaTeX kernel defines four page styles: `empty`, `plain`, `headings`, and `myheadings`. The `article` document class employs the `plain` page style for *all* pages.)

The instruction `\pagestyle{fancy}` instructs LaTeX to use the `fancy` page style instead of the `headings` page style for "all other pages", but it does not change the style setting for the first pages of chapter-like document units. And, as you've figured out by now, the `\tableofcontents` instruction initiates a new chapter-like unit.

- To override the default setting just for the table of contents, and assuming the ToC is less than a full page in length, you could execute

  ```
  \thispagestyle{fancy}
  ```

  immediately after `\tableofcontents`.
- If you want to replace the `plain` page style with `fancy` throughout the document, you could insert the instruction

  ```
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{}
  ```

  in the preamble (*after* loading the `fancyhdr` package, of course).
- Finally, if the ToC is longer than one page and you still want to apply the `fancy` page style to the ToC pages (and, presumably, the List of Tables and List of Figures pages as well), I suggest you execute

  ```
  \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
  \tocloftpagestyle{fancy}
  ```

  in the preamble.

Answer (score 3):

For a document with a table of contents of more than one page, redefining page style `plain` will be necessary. But then this will also change the footer of the first page of each chapter. If you don't want that, you can restrict the redefinition to the table of contents with a group, like the following.

```
{
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}%
\tableofcontents
\newpage
}
```